# TeX template for Addison Wesley textbooks?

Tags: fonts, templates

Is there a LaTeX template that emulates this particular format? There are a number of good physics textbooks that are typeset in a particular style that I like a lot, and the only common thread I see is that they were published by Addison-Wesley at some time or other. Some examples:

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modern_Quantum_Mechanics/010yDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=sakurai+quantum&printsec=frontcover

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Spacetime_and_Geometry/PTGdDwAAQBAJ?kptab=editions&gbpv=1

[https://www.amazon.com/Classical-Mechanics-3rd-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/0201657023/ref=sr_1_2?crid=1TITOJB4G8PUQ&keywords=safko+poole&qid=1644496945&sprefix=safko+poole%2Caps%2C201&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657023)

[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Electrodynamics-David-J-Griffiths/dp/1108420419/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=griffiths+electrodynamics&qid=1644497023&sprefix=griffiths+%2Caps%2C103&sr=8-2&asin=B075FT7QNZ&revisionId=fixed_format&format=4&depth=2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108420419)

I think the main text is in Times and the headers, page numbers, and running heads are Optima, but I could be wrong.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you asked Addison-Wesley?

Comment: Weren’t they absorbed by Pearson?

Comment: Haven't compiled this to see the result, but there is the add-wes package on CTAN. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/add-wes